# How to show the current play time of a video file in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, media-player, jtextfield

I calculate the time of the current play time of video:

```
public show_time_of_vedio_file(MediaPanel mediaPanel,JFrame_of_subtitle frame)
{

   //      for(;;)
            {
            double second=mediaPanel.mediaPlayer.getMediaTime().getSeconds();

            int second1=(int) second;
            int hour=second1/3600;
            second1=second1-hour*3600;
            int minute=second1/60;
            second1=second1-minute*60;
            double milisecond=(second-(int)second)*1000;
            int milisecond_1=(int) milisecond;
            String milisecond_string=String.valueOf(milisecond_1);
            String hour_string=String.valueOf(hour);
            String minute_string=String.valueOf(minute);
            String second_string=String.valueOf(second1);
            if(hour_string.length()==1)
                hour_string="0".concat(hour_string);
            if(minute_string.length()==1)
                minute_string="0".concat(minute_string);
            if(second_string.length()==1)
                second_string="0".concat(second_string);
            if(milisecond_string.length()==2)
                milisecond_string="0".concat(milisecond_string);
            else if(milisecond_string.length()==1)
                milisecond_string="0".concat("0".concat(milisecond_string));


            frame.show_time_jTextField.setText(String.format("%s:%s:%s,%s", hour_string,minute_string,second_string,milisecond_string));
        }
}
```

Now I want to show the this time in `JTextField` all the time when the video is playing
and when the video is not play I want to show `00:00:00,000`.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: BTW - 1 person has entered a comment as an answer to your question that specifically referred to the incorrect spelling of 'vedio'.  2 people have edited the question to correct the 5 or so times it was incorrectly spelled, then I was astonished to see an edit from you that broke the spelling again.  ***Stop playing silly games!***  Spell the word correctly & do not sabotage the efforts of others who correct it when it is wrongly spelled!  I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Sorry, for this....
My little brother did this........

Comment: *"My little brother did this"*  Put a password on your machine or stop lying to us, whichever is the case. :(

Answer (score 5):

> ..want to show the this time in `JTextField`..

Use a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for this instead.  E.G.

[image: JProgressBar]

See [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for more details.

> ..not play I want to show `00:00:00,000`.

See [JProgressBar.setString(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString%28java.lang.String%29).  The progress-bar in the upper right of this GUI shows use of a more 'media friendly' string.

[image: DukeBox]

Comment: But I need to show the current time of vedio in a time format that is hh:mm:ss,msmsms.

Comment: But you need to change the string.  I wrote *"more 'media friendly' string"* rather than *"string to your exact requirement"*.  To put that another way:  ***"Batteries not included."***

Comment: @Animesh Kumar Paul this excelent answer fully answering your question, +1

Comment: Can anyone give me an example...??